# How to get Json Response in swift 3.0?

Tags: json, swift3, alamofire, xcode8

I am geting JSON response in different format in XCode 8 as it use to appear in XCode 7.3

Because of that my app stopped responding. I am sharing the screenshot of my response.

This is the code I am using

```
func MobileNumber(_ notification : Notification){
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        if let notificationDict = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo{
            print(notificationDict)
            if let dataDict = notificationDict["Data"] as? NSDictionary{
                print(dataDict)
                if let status = dataDict["response"] as? Int{
                    switch status{
                    case 1:
                        if let data = dataDict["data"] as? NSDictionary{
                            if let mobileNumber = data["phone"] as? String{
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(mobileNumber, forKey: DefaultsKey.phoneNumber.rawValue)
                                print(mobileNumber)
                            }
                            UpdateFrame1()
                        }
```

JSON Response :

```
Data]: 243 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
    data =     {
        "__v" = 0;
        "_id" = 5833e131de2fe2342b0d0410;
        code = "<null>";
        "created_at" = "2016-11-22T06:09:53.097Z";
        "expiry_date" = "2016-11-22T06:09:53.097Z";
        phone = 9********;
        status = active;
    };
    message = "Resending your unused auth code";
    response = 1;
}
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 501493300.746, "Initial Response Time": 501493302.862, "Request Completed Time": 501493302.868, "Serialization Completed Time": 501493302.872, "Latency": 2.116 secs, "Request Duration": 2.122 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.003 secs, "Total Duration": 2.126 secs }
```

Comment: Show us the code that you using.

Comment: Additionally show the old and the new JSON response. And copy and paste it as text into the question (instead of using a screenshot).

Comment: Cannot show the old response because of xcode update and shortage of time sir.

Comment: @NiravD I just updated my code, please check

Comment: @RajatAttri Simply change line `if let dataDict = notificationDict["Data"] as? NSDictionary{` with `if let dataDict = notificationDict["SUCCESS"] as? NSDictionary{`

Comment: @NiravD didn't work.

Comment: @RajatAttri Can you show me the response of this `if let notificationDict = notification.userInfo as? [String: Any]{ print(notificationDict) }` Now show me the output of `notificationDict` here.

Comment: @NiravD Can u share ur email id? So that I can share response?

Comment: @RajatAttri You have already added response in your question, what i'm trying to say is add my above comment code and add the output of that print statement here

Comment: [Request]: https://************************
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170239260> { URL: ***} { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Accept";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
} }
[Data]: 23 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
    data =     {
        "id" = 58344a;
        code = "<null>";
        phn = ***;
        stats = active;
    };
    response = 1;
}

Comment: @NiravD Above written is the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
let val = userInfo["SUCSESS"]
        if  let jsonData = (val as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        {
            do{
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers )

                if let dict = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject]
                {

                    print("YOUR PHONE NUM \((dict as? [String : AnyObject])?["data"]?["phone"])")
                }

            }catch let error as NSError {
                print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")


            }

        }
```

Comment: I have to do it the way I have stated in Question, your way will work when we are hitting API and we are getting response for it.

Comment: You can use "dataDict" instead "userInfo" as mentioned above,that is working for me